# visual studio cannot open my project error npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio

i want to run and debuuging my project but i have this error

when i put npm start

```
  /home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
```

throw err;
^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/public'
at FSWatcher. (node:internal/fs/watchers:244:19)
at Object.watch (node:fs:2251:34)
at createFsWatchInstance (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:119:15)
at setFsWatchListener (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:166:15)
at NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:331:14)
at NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:567:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:617:16)
at async /home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:451:21
at async Promise.all (index 0)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:647:10)
at NodeFsHandler._addToNodeFs (/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:645:18)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async /home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:451:21
at async Promise.all (index 0) {
errno: -28,
syscall: 'watch',
code: 'ENOSPC',
path: '/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/public',
filename: '/home/aymen/Téléchargements/app/public'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, your project is hitting your system's file watchers limit

To fix this, on your terminal, try:

```bash
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```